# How to know the size of my Django pages before deployment?

Tags: django, web-performance

I am developing my very first website. I would like to know the page size before attempting to deploy it and whether I am doing something really silly/inefficient.

Is there at least any tool similar to https://tools.pingdom.com/ while in development?

[image: pingdom]

Comment: What do you think is not available when  running locally? You can try using lighthouse from the dev tools to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This still does not tell the overall webpage size but gives a breakdown of loading times per element and tips to improve it.

Thanks to Marco to point out this can be found in Chrome browser.

Navigate to the webpage, press `Ctrl + Shift + I` in Windows and search `Lighthouse` in the right arrow icon circled in red.

[image: Lighthouse in Chrome]